# SyntaxError in Python handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using urlfetch available from Google App Engine to fetch URLs content. But I am getting 500 Internal Server Error.

Here is the complete app code that I am using :-

**compare-hatke.py**

```
import urllib2
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import datetime

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def curlTry:
        url = "http://www.google.com/"
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            print(result.content)

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],debug=True)


def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**app.yaml**

```
application: compare-hatke
version: 3
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: compare-hatke.app
```

Here is the **error log**. I am not able to understand the syntax error they are mentioning

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 269, in _LoadHandler
    raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name))
ImportError: <module 'compare-hatke' from '/base/data/home/apps/s~compare-hatke/3.365290288779373200/compare-hatke.pyc'> has no attribute app
```

Please tell me where I am missing. Thanks !

Comment: This is a basic Python syntax error. It has nothing to do with urlfetch.

Comment: OK, but I am getting a different error now :(

Comment: Please don't change the question after people have already answered and commented on it. Ask a new one instead.

Comment: that's ok. but it will be too good for me if you answer this one right here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a python2.5 style app definition with a main() method.

You need to revisit the 2.7 tutorial https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld and you will see you app should look like

```
import urllib2
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.ext import webapp2

import datetime

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def curlTry(self):
        url = "http://www.google.com/"
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        if result.status_code == 200:
           self.response.write(result.content)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],debug=True)
```

to match your app.yaml definition.  Your app.yaml refers to `compare-hatke.app` which means that `compare-hatke.py` needs `app` defined in it somewhere, (as per my example)

In addition your should be using webapp2 with 2.7, and not sure how your curlTry class method is going to get called, but that is a seperate issue to your question.

I suggest you start from scratch and work through the 2.7 tutorials as you a missing a few bits here .

I have amended the code to reflect that response.write shoudl be used, and made the handler an instance method rather  a class method.  However you current app.yaml won't map a GET/POST request to curlTry based on your posted app.yaml and current code.  Have another look at the tutorial I have linked here.

T

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I think on;y issue remaining is that it is not printing anything right now. I guess it is because the time it is executed, results are not yet fetched. Is there any onrequestArrival handler or something in python ? That would be great help !

Comment: You can't print with that handler, you need to self.response.write().  See the tutorial I mentioned.  As your code listed has a classmethod and therefore won't have a webapp2 response object available. I didn't fix all of your code in my reposted example.

Answer (score 2):

A Python method in a class needs to refer to the self parameter in the function definition in order to identify the instance that it belongs to. This is your basic syntax error.

Correcting that, you still need to set up a routing so that your MainPage class can handle the GET request. This is most easily done by having a get method in GAE. The documentation shows you other methods once you have this working.

Try this:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self): # responds to http GET, and adds self parameter
        url = "http://www.google.com/"
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            print(result.content)
```

Comment: Sorry, but making the modifications just changed the error. It says some module not found. Please help !